# Drawing *.ico file on wxWidgets

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I tried to write a program to draw all possible sizes of an image from *.ico file.

My code for this:

```
<!-- language: lang-cpp -->

#include <wx/wx.h>
#include <wx/colour.h>
#include <wx/filesys.h>

wxString path("c:\\...\\*.ico");

class MyApp: public wxApp
{
    virtual bool OnInit();
};

class MyFrame: public wxFrame
{
public:
    MyFrame(const wxString& title, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size);
    void paint(wxPaintEvent& event);
private:
    DECLARE_EVENT_TABLE()
};

BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(MyFrame, wxFrame)
    EVT_PAINT(MyFrame::paint)
END_EVENT_TABLE()

IMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp)

bool MyApp::OnInit()
{
    MyFrame *frame = new MyFrame("ICO Test", wxPoint(50, 50), wxSize(600,300) );
    frame->Show(true);
    SetTopWindow(frame);
    return true;
}

MyFrame::MyFrame(const wxString& title, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size)
: wxFrame( NULL, -1, title, pos, size )
{
    wxInitAllImageHandlers();
}


void MyFrame::paint(wxPaintEvent& event)
{
    wxPaintDC dc(this);

    int count = wxImage::GetImageCount(path, wxBITMAP_TYPE_ICO);
    dc.DrawText(wxString::Format(wxT("count is: %ld"), count), 40, 20);
    int x_pos = 20;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        wxImage image;
        if (image.LoadFile(path, wxBITMAP_TYPE_ICO, i ))
        {
            wxIcon icon;
            icon.CopyFromBitmap(wxBitmap(image));
            dc.DrawIcon(icon, wxPoint(x_pos, 40));
            int h = icon.GetHeight();
            dc.DrawText(wxString::Format(wxT("%ld"), h), x_pos + 3, 45 + h);
            x_pos += (icon.GetWidth() + 4);
        }
    }
}
```

[Icon](http://www.veryicon.com/icon/ico/System/Oxygen/apps%20utilities%20terminal.ico) for testing. (which I found by searching on Google)

All works fine except 256x256 size (it doesn't draw them).

The application throws this error: `DIB Header: Image width > 32767 pixels for file.`.

My system:

- Windows 7 x64
- MinGW 4.8.2
- wxWidgets 3.0

Comment: I think the error (assert?) got mangled because I don't see this string anywhere in wxWidgets sources.

Comment: Sorry @VZ I make typing mistake forgot '>' it is my fault. That string came from here %wxWidgets%\src\common\imagbmp.cpp  line: 1032.

Comment: @VZ I post all my code for test. Can you reproduce same behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a bug in wxWidgets, so you should [report it](http://trac.wxwidgets.org/newticket), ideally providing a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) and at least the ICO file showing the problem.

Comment: I can confirm that this is a bug or, rather, a missing feature: wxWidgets code can't parse PNG icons data. You should still be able to load the icon from resources under Windows, as this uses the native icon loading function, but to do it from external files and, especially, on the other platforms, wxWidgets code needs to be modified to allow it. It shouldn't be difficult, but someone needs to do it...

Comment: Notice that thanks to [a contribution](http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/15918) from Artur Wieczorek, wxWidgets does support 256*256 PNG icons with transparency now, so you just need to upgrade to 3.0.1 to make this work.

Comment: Wow, wxWidgets team works faster compared to Qt team or it pure luck in relation to this bug. Any way Thank you very much guys. You the best.